# PositionConstraint goal for robot arm: Unable to construct goal representation

Tags: ros, moveit

I have a setting of ROS indigo, Gazebo under Ubuntu 14.04. Under ROS, moveit node is running. A robot arm IRB120 is simulated and standing in Gazebo. I have a node that uses `moveit` (move_group node) to *plan a path (trajectory)* for for the *destination* that Bob wants. The planned trajectory will be sent to Gazebo to be shown later.

There is two approaches that Bob can use to describe the destination:

1. Angles of each joints of the arm: using an array of six numbers (for six joints of the arm), the form of each joint and shin is defined. This approach works fine. It uses the `JointConstraint` class:

   double goal_poses [] = {0.52, 0.50, 0.73, -0.02, 0.31, 6.83};
     for(int i = 0 ; i < 6; i++) // iterate over joints of the arm.
     {
       moveit_msgs::JointConstraint jc;
       jc.weight = 1.0;
       jc.tolerance_above = 0.0001;
       jc.tolerance_below = 0.0001;
       jc.position = goal_poses[i];
       jc.joint_name = names[i];
       goal_constraint.joint_constraints.push_back(jc);
     }
2. Define the location and direction of the end effector only. I can not use this approach. I have used the `PositionConstraint` class.

**Problem in short**: I can describe a destination using `JointConstraint` class, But I don't know how to describe it in `PositionConstraint` class. **How to describe a goal, by just pointing out where the end effector should be?**

How i describe the goal in `PositionConstraint` format: (I point out where the end effector should be and what it's orientation should be.)

```
  moveit_msgs::PositionConstraint pc;
  pc.weight = 1.0;
  geometry_msgs::Pose p;
  p.position.x = 0.3; // not sure if feasible position
  p.position.y = 0.3; // not sure if feasible position
  p.position.z = 0.3; // not sure if feasible position
  pc.link_name="tool0";
  p.orientation.x = 0;
  p.orientation.y = 0;
  p.orientation.z = 0;
  p.orientation.w = 1;
  pc.constraint_region.mesh_poses.push_back(p);
  goal_constraint.position_constraints.push_back(pc);
```

But When the request is sent, server responds with:

```
[ERROR] [1527689581.951677797, 295.242000000]: Unable to construct goal representation
```

Note:

In both cases, I add the `goal_constraint` to the `trajectory_request`:

```
trajectory_request.goal.request.goal_constraints.push_back(goal_constraint);
// add other details to trajectory_request here...
```

`trajectory_request` is to be sent to the `move_group`. (by publishing the `trajectory_request` on the `/move_group/goal` topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different solution solved the problem of **describing goal with end-effector orientation and location**:

Instead of publishing the goal on a `topic` for another node to parse and read, we can use the `moveit` library function `computeCartesianPath`. (In this example the code to publish the trajectory is commented and partially missing)

```
void planTo(std::vector<double> coordinate, std::vector<double> orientation){

  geometry_msgs::Pose p;
  p.orientation.w = 1.0;
  p.position.x = coordinate[0];
  p.position.y = coordinate[1];
  p.position.z = coordinate[2];

  tf::Quaternion q = tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(
      orientation[0],orientation[1],orientation[2]);

  p.orientation.x = q.getX();
  p.orientation.y = q.getY();
  p.orientation.z = q.getZ();
  p.orientation.w = q.getW();

  std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> goals;
  goals.push_back(p);

  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup mg("manipulator");
  mg.setStartStateToCurrentState();

  // load the path in the `trajectory` variable:
  moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory trajectory;
  mg.computeCartesianPath(goals, 0.01, 0.0, trajectory);
  // publish to gazebo:
  // trajectory.joint_trajectory.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  // publisher.publish(trajectory.joint_trajectory);
}
```

I solved this a few months ago and unfortunately i do not remember the exact source/tutorial.